# How can I successively subract values from int elements in a list until I reach the end of my list?

Tags: python-3.x

So what I'm overall trying to accomplish is shifting a list containing multiple int elements successively by a variable that holds an unknown amount of ints.

Example:
list = [11,2,107,103,97]

key = '18'

if we were subtracting the updated list should look like this:
updatedList = [10, -6, 106, 95, 96]

In all the for loops that I've tried my errors consist of ints not being iterable. When I tried iterating it as a string or a list for some reason only one element was picked up. I could even specify which element by list slicing but it was always one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
a = [11,2,107,103,97]
key = '18'
b = [i-int(key[I%len(key)]) for I,i in enumerate(a)]
```

Since you don't know the length of the key I used the modulus (%) operator which will never exceed the correct indices of 'key'.

Comment: thanks so much! that works perfectly. Could you tell me if I'm understanding it properly? So my element - [the element of my key at this index] do this for each element in my enumerated (a)? Sorry I'm new but I'd really like to understand.

Comment: Enumerate returns both the index (I) and element (i) of the list a. All I'm doing here is working my way through a while cycling through the elements of key (using I%len(key)). If len(a)=5 and len(key)=3, [I%len(key) for I in range(len(a))] = [0,1,2,0,1].

Answer (score 2):

```
my_list = [11,2,107,103,97]
key = [1,8]
updated_list = [my_list[i]-key[i % len(key)] for i in range(len(my_list))]
```

or, if key is a string as in the original post,

```
my_list = [11,2,107,103,97]
key = '18'
updated_list = [my_list[i]-int(key[i % len(key)]) for i in range(len(my_list))]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a natural way to cycle through the key, using [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle). We'll use `map(int, key)` to convert the digits of `key` into integers that can be subtracted.

```py
>>> nums = [11, 2, 107, 103, 97]
>>> key = '18'
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> [ x - k for x, k in zip(nums, cycle(map(int, key))) ]
[10, -6, 106, 95, 96]
```